# Cannot convert string to bool

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error: Cannot implicitly convert from 'string' to 'bool'
sl.CustomerRefNbr is a string from my table design

```
    using (AH_ODS_DBEntities db = new AH_ODS_DBEntities())
    {
        string rs = db.Sales.Where(sl => sl.CustomerRefNbr);
```

I have tried:

```
bool rs = db.Sales.Where(sl => sl.CustomerRefNbr).ToString();
string rs = db.Sales.Where(sl => sl.CustomerRefNbr);
Convert.ToBoolean(rs);
```

I'm being blind again.
What I'm trying to do is just get the data from CustomerRefNbr column and put it on a list.

Comment: Why do you believe it should have a default conversion to boolean?

Comment: How could string have an implicit conversion to a boolean?  What would be the result of `bool result = "cheese"`?

Comment: Maybe he's trying to convert "true" and "false"  to their respective boolean equivalents?

Comment: Probably not, given the column name "CustomerRefNbr"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The where clause expects a boolean clause, and you're giving it what is probably either a string or numeric value via the CustomerRefNbr.  If you want to select all these values to a list as you say, use the select Linq method:
`vars = db.Sales.Select(sl => sl.CustomerRefNbr).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
string rs = db.Sales.Where(sl => sl.CustomerRefNbr);
```

Doesn't actually make sense. You are selecting Sales where the customer reference number is.. what? And then assigning the list of sales to a string?

It looks kind of like you're trying to say you want the `CustomerRefNbr` as output, but then you don't say which row's value you want.

The reason you get an error about trying to convert a string to bool is because `Where` is expecting an expression that returns a boolean. Rows where the boolean is true will be included in the results. It's trying to interpret `sl.CustomerRefNbr` as a boolean and failing.

Even if it worked, the result would be a collection of `Sale` objects, not a string, so you'd get another error.

You need to specify which row(s) you want with `Where` and which column(s) you want with `Select`.

For example:

```
 string rs = db.Sales.Where(sl => sl.Id == 123).Select(sl => sl.CustomerRefdNbr).First();
```

Notice that the `Where` part is an expression that returns a boolean.

Because the result is still a collection (even though you know there's only one result), you have to call `First` to get the first result into a single `string`.

If you want *all* `CustomerRefNbr` values, then you can leave out the `Where`:

```
List<string> refs = db.Sales.Select(sl => sl.CustomerRefNbr).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to save 'Sale' with bool property or at least as int.
But anyway, for your task next solution helps to avoid parsing errors.

```
var res = db.Sales.Where(x =>x.CustomerRefNbr!= null && x.CustomerRefNbr.ToUpper()=="TRUE");
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.Sales.Where(sl => sl.CustomerRefNbr)` results in compile time error because `where` expects `predicate` (something that returns true or false) and you are not supplying one.

What you probably want is `Select` instead of `Where`. 
`db.Sales.Select(sl => sl.CustomerRefNbr);` which again returns collection of CustomerRefNbr (`IEnumerable<string>`) not a single value (`string`)

Assigning "collection" to a variable of type `string` ("single") value doesn't make sense and results again in `compile` error.

If you want single value from `IEnumerable` collection, you could use `db.Sales.Select(sl => sl.CustomerRefNbr).First()`. This gives you "CustomerRefNbr" of `First` "Sale" out of all the "Sales" .

Now, if you want to filter the "Sales" with CustomerRefNbr, you could first *filter* with a `where` clause and `select` CustomerRefNbr.

```
db.Sales.Where(s1=>s1.CustomerRefNbr=="123").Select(s2 => s2.CustomerRefNbr).First();
```

Now this gives you a `First` "CustomerRefNbr" out of all the sales where the CustomerRefNbr is "123"

I still don't understand why would you want to `convert` "CustomerRefNbr" to `boolean`?